# What is 'The Inferior'?

Tags: gdb

What is ***The Inferior*** when debugging Qt Applications?

e.g. found in the following message window:

*The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the context of GDB, see https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs.html

"GDB represents the state of each program execution with an object called an inferior. An inferior typically corresponds to a process, but is more general and applies also to targets that do not have processes."